# Файл создаётся через раз

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Через скрипт, посредством функции fopen($file, "w"). Проблема в том, что файл почему-то создаётся через раз. Права к каталогам стоят 777, в чём проблема я не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

```
$file_open = @fopen($file, "w");
        if($file_open){
            $file_write = fwrite($file_open,$write_whis);
        }
```

Comment: Вам стоит поделиться частью своего кода, функция fopen() ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: Дополнил текст.

Comment: Методом телепатии предположу что все это обернуто в функциюю foo(), которая вызывается if (rand(0,100)<50) foo(); Покажите еще больше кода, чтобы видеть всю логику )))

Comment: что содержит переменная $file ???

Comment: уберите к чертям собаку перед вызовом метода, с 95% вероятностью она глушит именно ту ошибку, которая вам скажет о причинах такого поведения. Если нужно глушить ошибки, используйте как минимум пустой обработчик и set_error_handler и restore_error_handler (лучше - класс с внутренней логикой обработки, один из методов которого ставится обработчиком), эту собаку в потом в коде будете пару суток искать.

Comment: плюс если сменить код на такой

    if($file_open)
        $file_write = fwrite($file_open,$write_whis);
    else
        die($file); // или log($file), Logger::log($file) и т.п.

то увидите путь, в котором может быть забыт слеш, перепутаны местами директории или который просто ведет в еще не созданную приложением директорию - на это все уходит добрых процентов 50% вероятности ошибки, которая решается за три секунды.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще феерично: влепить собаку перед fopen(), забить на анализ ошибки, после чего выдать "в чём проблема я не понимаю" :-)

```
if( $fh = fopen($file, 'w') )
{
    /* do something */
    fclose($fh);
}
else
{
    print_r( error_get_last() );
}
```

И ваши волосы будут шелковистыми.